# How to get Amazon music to work in firefox or chrome

Tags: flash, amazon

I have updated and installed adobe but I am receiving this message error still. And Amazon music will not stream at all, I am 100% new to Ubuntu/ Linux and just learning. Guidance much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What Ubuntu version do you use? Which browser? How exactly did you "install adobe"?

Comment: With default settings and `adobe-flashplugin` installed from the Canonical Partner repository (which you must explicitly enable during install, or in the Software & Updates settings page), Amazon Music will work OK in both Chromium and Firefox.